# Form is coming back as validated, even though fields are not filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form here, I'm just trying to make it NOT come back as valid of the rules are not met, however no matter what, if no fields are filled in, or only partial, it will always come back as "True". I don't get any errors, so I can't seem root out the issue

```
<form id="appForm">
    <input name='project_title' type='text' />
    <input name='county' type='text' />
    <input type='submit'>
</form>


$(function (){

    $("#appform").validate({
    rules:{
        project_title:{
            required:true
        },
        county:{
            required:true
        }
    }
});

$("#appForm").on('submit', function (e) {
    var isvalidate=$("#appForm").valid();
    console.log(isvalidate);
    if(isvalidate) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
});
```

I always get the alert that says True no matter what fields are filled in / not filled in, and the console will always return "true" as well

Comment: I wonder what's the output of the `console.log` line

Comment: @OfirBaruch It says True as well:  screen shot: http://puu.sh/313dz.png

Comment: Should $("#appform").validate be $("#appForm").validate (with capital F)

Answer (score 5):

Okk..

You are applying wrong selector ,, It's Capital `F`

```
$("#appForm").validate({
```

Working Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/LN4Ey/

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I'd do so :)

Comment: ....................... I hate myself so much right now. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: @user2288860 It's advised that you accept this as the answer to your question by clicking the green tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `e.preventDefault()` to the `else` clause

```
if(isvalidate) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I changed it to return false, and still getting the same results: Screenshot: http://puu.sh/313dz.png

Comment: Can you move this to http://jsbin.com/ ?